# Jenkins: how to control projects based on name using regexp?

Tags: jenkins, directory, role-based-access-control

For each application, we create a AppName.Dev and AppName.Rel project in Jenkins to build the Development and Release branch. Now we want to allow only certain people to modify/run the Release builds.

Currently we are using this Role/Folder based access control plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin

e.g., I have a Role/rule called TE/TS.* so everyone in domain group TS has full access to projects inside TE/TS folder. Inside this folder has projects such as App1.Dev, App1.Rel and App2.Dev, App2.Rel,etc.

Now how can I allow everyone in TS still have full access to *.Dev project, but not the *.Rel project, then only have a TS_REL group have full access to *.Rel projects.

Another approach would be separating .*Dev projects into a TE/TS/Dev folder and *.Rel projects into TE/TS/Rel folder.

Answer (score 2):

The following rule can restrict users to all projects with name ended with .Release in folder TE/TS.

```
TE/TS.*.Release
```